# I have added a column to a MySQL table but no data is showing

Tags: php, mysql

I successfully added a column into a table in MySQL when I insert data via a PHP form, the email and the password are added successfully but not the username.

When I display the table the "Usernames" tables remains blank.

Here is the PHP form:

```
<html>   
<head>    
<title>Register</title>    
</head>    
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'xxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxxx';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

    if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    {
   $email = addslashes ($_POST['email']);
   $password = addslashes ($_POST['password']);
   $usernames = addslashes ($_POST['usernames']);

}
else
{
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $usernames = $POST['usernames'];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email,usernames,password) VALUES ('$email', '$usernames',   ENCRYPT('$password'))";

mysql_select_db('dbname');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
 <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Your Email @foo.com</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Your Username</td>
<td><input name="usernames" type="text" id="usernames"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Your Password</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Register">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the column for usernames using the command line:

```
 ALTER TABLE tbname ADD usernames VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL;
```

It was added but when a user registers, his username is not showing. Only the email and the encrypted password are added.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing to do: check if the username is actually present in the insert statement by dumping that to some logfile (e.g. using `syslog`).

Comment: Is the data in database? I guess you just have a bad select.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line 
`$usernames = $POST['usernames'];`

Change it to
`$usernames = $_POST['usernames'];`

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use mysql, use mysqli/pdo. Turn off magic quotes and if you stick with mysql (don't) switch `addslashes()` to `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

And you're having:

```
$usernames = $POST['usernames'];
```

Missing `_`:

```
$usernames = $_POST['usernames'];
```

But your database schema (namely `NOT NULL`) should take care of not having empty data, so also make sure that your select is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the mysql_* functions and at least escape all user input....

change

```
$usernames = $POST['usernames'];
```

to

```
$usernames = $_POST['usernames'];
```

When developing enable display_errors so you can easily spot this error:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```